# Google sign-in authorization suggestion

Tags: javascript, google-signin

Could you tell me please, what it is and how I can make such authorization on my site?
https://id.atlassian.com/login 
[image]
I do according to the instructions
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#before_you_begin 
but I only have the login button

```html
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

but I want to get the same window as in the image, with the offer to login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Google One-tap sign-up or Google yolo (you only log-in once).

According to their [website](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/), it's currently in closed beta.

Here is an usage example: https://github.com/zapier/google-yolo-inline